# AuthenticateAsServer - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to create a test client/server connection using the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listenerThread = new Thread(ListenerThreadEntry);
        listenerThread.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        socket.Connect("localhost", Port);

        var rawStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        var stream = new SslStream(rawStream, false, VerifyServerCertificate);
        var certificate = new X509Certificate(CertsPath + @"test.cer");
        var certificates = new X509CertificateCollection(new[] { certificate });
        stream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost", certificates, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    private static bool VerifyServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    static void ListenerThreadEntry()
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        listener.Start();

        var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        var serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2(CertsPath + @"\test.pfx");
        var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, true, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
```

And getting "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure" error message in the AuthenticateAsServer method. Certificate was created and saved to file using these commands:

```
makecert.exe -r -pe -n "CN=localhost" -a sha1 -sky exchange -sv test.pvk test.cer
pvk2pfx -pvk test.pvk -spc test.cer -pfx test.pfx
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see where in your process you add trust to the certificate you use for authentication. Passing `false` as parameter 4 to `AuthenticateAsServer()` only skips the check for revocation, it does not skip the check for trust in general.

So you have the following choices to make it work:

- Do not generate the certificate yourself but have it generated by a certificate authority that is trusted in Windows by default. This will cost some money, but there are also some cheap CAs out there, it needn't be a Thawte certificate.
- Add trust to the certificate by importing it to the list of personal certificates
- If you already created a self-signed CA certificate that was already added to the list of trusted root certificates (which is common in companies or organizations), sign your certificate with that CA certificate
- Do not authenticate at all (but likely you do not want that)

Answer (score 3):

check these steps, seems to be working,

```
1)First save the certificate in a file
2)Run MMC
3)Open the Certificate Manager (certmgr.msc in C:\Windows\System32)
4)You will see it opens 'Certificates - Current User'
5)In the menu, choose File, Add/Remove Snap-In
6)Now press Add, select 'Certificates' and select 'Computer Account'
7)Select the Local Computer
8)Now you have two snap-ins:
9)Certificates - Current User
10)Certificates (Local Computer)
11)Now import the certificate in "Certificates (Local Computer)\Trusted Root Certificates\Certificates"
```

Comment: Do I have to add it to the global certificate store?